# How to represent Objects in Functional Python?

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary

I don't have experience with Python.
It is this thing that keeps bothering me few days. I tried to find an answer but unfortunately i didn't succeed. Since i am reading data from file to in-memory, i thought of way to represent it as:

```
students [{id: [firstname,lastname,password]}, {id: [firstname,lastname,password]}]
```

How this approach seem to you? And how could i iterate through this, and check for login credentials? It's Python 3

Comment: What does this have to do with functional programming? You are using objects there anyway. You question is unclear. If you just want to know how to iterate over such a data-structure, there are plenty of duplicates on that topic already.

Comment: I can't write classes, so how can i represent real life objects?I am sorry if i wasn't clear..

Comment: It seems you already are thinking about using the built-in container classes in Python. I'm not sure why there is a restriction on the use of class definitions... but again, if your question is how to iterate over such a data structure, there are plenty of questions on that topic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You define *students* as an array of objects (each is a `dict`): good

You define each student's attributes as an array: not so good.

That array is the value of a property with the name `id`: confusing.

The more natural way to store such data is like this:

```
 students = [{
     'id': 1,
     'firstname': 'Mary',
     'lastname': 'Jones',
     'password': 'secret'
 }, {
     'id': 2,
     'firstname': 'Liam',
     'lastname': 'McEnzie',
     'password': '9#4t&$X'
 }]
```

Comment: Perhaps maybe a `namedtuple`?

Comment: Yes, that is a suitable data structure as well. Just note that they are immutable.

Answer (score 0):

If you are just wanting to bind data fields together given a regular naming scheme, a `namedtuple` will work great. It has the added benefit of being immutable, if you are trying to maintain a purely functional approach:

```
from collections import namedtuple

# namedtuple is actually a class-factory:
Student = namedtuple("Students", ['id','firstname','lastname','password'])

# notice i'm using a plain tuple as a container - again, we want immutability
# for a functional approach
students = (
    Student(id=1, firstname='Rick', lastname='Sanchez', password='rickkyticky'),
    Student(id=2, firstname='Morty', lastname='Smith', password='password'),
    Student(id=3, firstname='Summer', lastname='Smith', password='tinkles')
)
```

You can iterate over this like you would almost anything else in Python, using for-loops or, if you'd rather be more functional, using comprehensions (in this case, really a generator-expression fed into a `tuple` constructor):

```
>>> for s in students:
...   print(s.password)
... 
rickkyticky
password
tinkles
>>> passwords = tuple(s.password for s in students)
>>> passwords
('rickkyticky', 'password', 'tinkles')
>>>
```

`namedtuple` is faster and significantly more memory efficient than a `dict`.